Generate a default mapping on TypeScript
I have an interface like this (but with over 20 fields)
export interface HouseDetails {
    title: string | undefined;
    url: URL;
    address?: string;
    logo?: URL;
    price?: number;
    sq_meters?: number;
}

And I want to generate a record with the keys of HouseDetails but all of its values set to a default value (for example, the empty string ""). This is the code I tried, but when I print it to a console, it is an empty object:
function generateDefaultMapping<T extends Object, D>(default_value: D): Record<keyof T, D> {
  return Object.fromEntries(Object.keys({} as T).map((key) => [key, default_value])) as Record<keyof T, D>;
}

// Use the function to create a default mapping for HouseDetails
const default_mapping<Record<keyof HouseDetails, string> = generateDefaultMapping<HouseDetails, string>("");
console.log(default_mapping) // {}

I think the problem is that this does not work like C++ templates, but, is there any way of doing it?

The construct as T is named "type assertion" and all it does is to tell to the TypeScript compiler "I know that this object does not match the type T but please act like it does. Trust me, I know what I'm doing". {} as T does not magically change {} to have the properties of T. In fact, it does not do anything, it does not produce anything in the generated JavaScript code.

The TS type system, including interfaces, is erased when TS is compiled to JS. There's no type information present from which to get default values. Any runtime information you need has to be added by you as JS code (e.g., write a schema object). You can derive types from values, but not vice versa. See the linked q/a for more information.
